# C++ - Initializing a 2D array with pointer notation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, srand

I'm working on 2D array in C++. I'm having trouble connecting the concepts of arrays and pointers. I know that they are related in terms of memory allocation and accessing elements. For example

```
int *arr;
int num = arr + 1*sizeof(int);
```

is the same as

```
int arr[];
int num = arr[1];
```

I'm trying to find the same connection between 2D arrays and pointers
Here's my code

```
void printGrid(int **arr) {
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   cout << setw(3);
   cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
 }
}

int main() {
 int **grid;
 srand(time(NULL));
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   grid[i][j] = rand() % 11;
  }
 }
 printGrid(grid);
}
```

When I compile this, it compiles. When I then try to run it, I get a segfault. Could someone please point out the error in my code?

Thanks SO

Comment: "int num = arr + 1*sizeof(int);" is NOT the same thing as arr[1].

Comment: there is no memory allocated to **grid. It is just a pointer. allocate space for it or set it to some size e.g. malloc or declare int grid[10][10];

Comment: There's no 2D array in your code. You have a pointer to a pointer, which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but to my understanding, array elements are stored consecutively in memory. arr points to the 0th element of the array. To access the first element, we then have to go (sizeof(int)) locations forward in memory. To access the second element, we must go 2*(sizeof(int)) locations forward in memory. Is that not right?

Comment: Since `arr` is a pointer to `int`s, adding 1 to the pointer advances to the next `int` sized entry, automatically.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you forget about pointers for the time being and focus on learning the standard library instead. In this particular case, you should be using `std::vector<int>` (or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, but I recommend against it) instead of an `int**` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int **grid;
 srand(time(NULL));
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   grid[i][j] = rand() % 11;
  }
 }
```

Where is the part which should allocate memory for the dynamic array? And possibly also for its elements? To remedy this you could have done

```
// Allocating memory for array and elements
int **grid = new int*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  grid[i] = new int[10];
}
// Now fill the array as you had in your code
//
...
// Deletion part
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  delete[] grid[i];
}
delete[] grid;
```

Also,

> I'm working on 2D array in C++. I'm having trouble connecting the
>   concepts of arrays and pointers. I know that they are related in terms
>   of memory allocation and accessing elements. For example
>
> int *arr; int num = arr + 1*sizeof(int);
>
> is the same as
>
> int arr[]; int num = arr[1];

No they are not the same. This would be same though:

```
int x[] = {0, 2, 3};
int *arr = x;
int num = *(arr + 1); //Look up pointer arithmetic; same as num=arr[1];
```

Comment: Ok. I see. How exactly do I allocate memory for a 2D array?

Answer (score 1):

`grid` is an uninitialized pointer.  Attempting to store anything through that pointer will result in undefined behaviour, such as segmentation failure.

Your code would need to look like:

```
 grid = new (int*) [10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     grid[i] = new int[10];
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         grid[i][j] = rand() % 11;
     }
}
```

(And you should `delete` the memory you allocated when you are finished)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    delete[] grid[i];
}
delete[] grid;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a follow-up question, if ou don't mind, how do I delete this 2D dynamically alloccated array. I know that for non-array variables, I have to write delete var; and for arrays I have to write delete [] arr; How do do the same to  a 2D array? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One big difference between `int ** ptrptr` and `int arr[X][Y]` is that `ptrptr` is a pointer to an `int` pointer, so it can hold a variable length of `int` pointers, each of which can represent different sized arrays like:

`ptrptr (ptrptr points to the beginning of three different sized arrays)
  ▼
address_1: 0 1 2 3
address_2: 4 5
address_3: 6 7 8`

For the `arr` variable, the array occuppies contiguous memory, and thus it can be visualized as a rectangle, so think of it like each row must have the same number of elements.